# Structure tag and name, why does a local variable declared as name compile?

Tags: c++, c, struct, language-features

In some code I saw recently there was a structure defined like this:

```
typedef struct tagMyStruct {
    int numberOne;
    int numberTwo;
} MYSTRUCT;
```

The way I understand this, `tagMyStruct` is the new data type and `MYSTRUCT` is a variable that is created right there.

At another place, this was used like this:

```
MYSTRUCT *pStruct = new MYSTRUCT;
```

and it compiled fine with Visual Studio 2010. How is that valid C++? I thought `MYSTRUCT` was a variable and not a type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. `tagMyStruct` is the name of the struct. In C, unlike C++, you must explicitly use the struct keyword every time you use the struct type. For example

```
tagMyStruct x; //error
struct tagMyStruct x; //OK
```

To avoid writing struct all the time, `struct tagMyStruct` is `typedef`'d to `MYSTRUCT`. Now you can write

```
MYSTRUCT x; //ok, same as struct tagMyStruct x;
```

What you thought this was (a variable definition) would be without the typedef keyword, like this

```
struct tagMyStruct {
    int numberOne;
    int numberTwo;
} MYSTRUCT;
```

BTW

```
MYSTRUCT pStruct = new MYSTRUCT; //error cannot convert MYSTRUCT* to MYSTRUCT
```

is not valid C or C++ anyway. Maybe you mean

```
MYSTRUCT* pStruct = new MYSTRUCT; //valid C++ (invalid C - use malloc instead of new in C)
```

hth

Comment: @BastiBechtold: It isn't an ampersand. It is an asterisk. Ampersand is & :)

Comment: Since when is 'new' valid in C? Also, it's worth emphasizing that this use of `typedef` is unnecessary and generally a bad idea in C++, exactly because C++ does not require you to use the `struct` keyword as part of the type name the way that C does. (Although sometimes you're stuck with it because you're inter-operating with legacy C code.)

Answer (score 6):

```
struct tagMyStruct { ... };
```

defines a new C++ type (class) called `tagMyStruct`.

```
struct { ... } MYSTRUCT;
```

defines a variable called `MYSTRUCT` with the given structure.

```
typedef struct { ... } MYSTRUCT;
```

defines a typedef called `MYSTRUCT` which is equivalent to the given anonymous struct.

```
typedef tagMyStruct struct { ... } MYSTRUCT;
```

defines a typedef called `MYSTRUCT` and a type called `tagMyStruct`. So MYSTRUCT is just a typedef for tagMyStruct. Therefore, `MYSTRUCT pStruct` defines a `tagMyStruct` called `pStruct`.

The assignment you gave is invalid, since `new MYSTRUCT` returns a *pointer* to `MYSTRUCT`.

Answer (score 3):

You are wrong, you are using `typedef`, i.e. `MYSTRUCT` is an alias for `tagMyStruct`. This explains how it's correct c++.

In order to create a variable, drop the typedef:

```
struct tagMyStruct {
    int numberOne;
    int numberTwo;
} MYSTRUCT;
```

Comment: These are alias `MYSTRUCT` and `tagMystruct` only in c++ not in C