# getting an error of undeclared node in compiling a simple linked list program

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, structure

**code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
     struct Node      //defining a node
     {
          int data;             //defining the data member
          struct Node *next;    //defining a pointer to Node type variable
     };

      struct Node *head;        //declaring a pointer variable 'head' to a Node type variable.   
      head=NULL;                //Since the head pointer now points nothing,so initialised with NULL.

      struct Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));//creating a node and storing its adrs in pointer 'temp'
     (*temp).data=2;          //node's data part is initialised.
     (*temp).next= NULL;    //the node points to nothing initially
     head=temp;             //head is initialised with address of the node,so now it points to the node 

     printf("%d",temp->data);
 }
```

Comment: Do not cast the return of `malloc()`. I think i should keep a template of this comment. :p

Comment: post the error message

Comment: As I am naive in it,would you please elaborate Sir?              
LinkedListImp.c:14:25: error: ‘Node’ undeclared (first use in this function) struct Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));//creating a node and storing its adrs in pointer 'temp'
                         ^
LinkedListImp.c:14:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
LinkedListImp.c:14:30: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    struct Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));//creating a node and storing its adrs in pointer 'temp'

Comment: The `error` message that you are getting, when you are trying to `compile`

Comment: compiled without typecasting,getting an error: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
    struct Node* temp =malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

Comment: @ABHISHEKSRIVASTAVA  use header `<stdlib.h>` to remove this warning.

Comment: Thanks ameyCU .Plz explain why we used it.

Comment: @ABHISHEKSRIVASTAVA  Function `malloc` is defined in this header .

Comment: @ameyCU Thanks.Can you site any resource to study about structure and pointers.

Comment: @ABHISHEKSRIVASTAVA  For standard reference -http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/  . for working programs -http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c/.

Comment: @ABHISHEKSRIVASTAVA  But mainly I found **Stackoverflow** very helpful . Regular  visiting and Q & A's are vary helpful.

Comment: Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/694576 Have your choice(s), read and come back.

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

instead of

```
 struct Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

because struct tags are in a different namespace than usual identifiers. So the struct keyword is necessary to specify that.Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334518/structure-tag-and-name-why-does-a-local-variable-declared-as-name-compile)

Moreover include `<stdlib.h>` else you will receive a warning that you are implicitly declaring malloc.